# how to change drag element style by react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

drag element img:

[image]

When dragging an element, it contains a background color。Is there anyone know how to resolve it ?

Comment: set radius for outer element .

Comment: I need to set radius for drag element instead of set it for outer element

Comment: Please add a link to your code

Comment: Not clear what's your issue here

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-platform-kgwj9，this is a code link

Comment: add transform: "translate(0px, 0px)" style for Card seems works